# How to call FullTextSearchKnowledgeArticle action using REST calls?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

How can we call MSCRM action using some HTTP Client request (c#)?
Can any one please assist on this.

Comment: Start with this - https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=1285&MessageKey=f0a63cc1-c364-43b4-88be-aed6b884383e&CommunityKey=dc83c23b-ede0-4070-ae7a-dd90859148a6&tab=digestviewer

Comment: I have followed below link. Here,how can i pass filter in query expression.Can any one assist on this.[https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/issues/38]

Comment: is that a valid link?

Comment: https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not covering this action, and I was able to pull this payload from couple of references. But I could not test this in my environment, please test it yourself.

The sample will look like this:

```
{
  "SearchText": "",
  "UseInflection": false,
  "RemoveDuplicates": false,
  "StateCode": 3,
  "QueryExpression": {
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.QueryExpression",
    "EntityName": "knowledgearticle",
    "ColumnSet": {
      "AllColumns": true
    },
    "Distinct": false,
    "NoLock": false,
    "PageInfo": {
      "PageNumber": 1,
      "Count": 10,
      "ReturnTotalRecordCount": true,
      "PagingCookie": ""
    },
    "LinkEntities": [],
    "Criteria": {
      "FilterOperator": "And",
      "Conditions": [
        {
          "EntityName": "knowledgearticle",
          "AttributeName": "languagelocaleid",
          "Operator": "Equal",
          "Values": [
            "56940B3E-300F-4070-A559-5A6A4D11A8A3"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/759).

Comment: I have  tried using that reference. But no luck. I am getting below error."message": "The ConditonOperator.Equal requires 1 value/s, not 0. Can someone please tell me how can i pass QuerExp?

Comment: @Sidhu everything is given there. Show us what you tried and what is the problem in question. No one will do your homework

Comment: I tried based on above payload and getting that error. I have't changed anything in payload.The problem is in this area->  "Operator": "Equal",
          "Values": [
            "56940B3E-300F-4070-A559-5A6A4D11A8A3"
          ].

Comment: @Sidhu edit the question and add details. Try simple filters instead of EntityReference to see any issues. Finally, always you can create ticket with MS for assistance or create an issue in github page for sample code.

Comment: @Sidhu was my answer helpful?

Comment: Sorry...Still i am trying.

Answer (score 0):

Make a POST request to the the following URL.

[Your organization root URL]/api/data/v9.1/FullTextSearchKnowledgeArticle

Here is one sample payload that works. You can optionally add additional filters to filter the search result.

```
{
   "SearchText":"test",
   "UseInflection":true,
   "RemoveDuplicates":true,
   "StateCode":3,
   "QueryExpression":{
      "@odata.type":"Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.QueryExpression",
      "EntityName":"knowledgearticle",
      "ColumnSet":{
         "AllColumns":true
      },
      "PageInfo":{
         "PageNumber":1,
         "Count":10
      },
     "Orders":[
         {
            "AttributeName":"modifiedon",
            "OrderType":"Descending"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Refer the link below for sample code for connecting to Dynamics.
[CDSWebApiService class library (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/samples/cdswebapiservice)

Answer (score 0):

Take this for an answer I could finally figure it out from the below Power Apps Sample for WebAPI which helped me figure out how to supply values of conditional expression inside query expression.
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/blob/efd91060156ecca74fd674a4613a38b64df13858/dataverse/webapi/C%23-NETx/BulkOperations/Utility.cs

```
{
"QueryExpression": {
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.QueryExpression",
    "ColumnSet": {
        "Columns": ["title", "description", "content"]
    },
    "Criteria": {
        "Conditions": [{
                "AttributeName": "languagelocaleid",
                "EntityName": "knowledgearticle",
                "Operator": "Equal",
                "Values": [{
                        "Type": "System.Guid",
                        "Value": "d026c011-4c03-4bfd-93d7-017f480ed54d"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "FilterOperator": "And"
    },
    "Distinct": false,
    "EntityName": "knowledgearticle",
    "NoLock": false,
    "PageInfo": {
        "Count": 100,
        "PageNumber": 1,
        "PagingCookie": "",
        "ReturnTotalRecordCount": true
    }
},
"RemoveDuplicates": false,
"SearchText": "book",
"StateCode": 3,
"UseInflection": true
```

}